# compiled AngularJS html validation tool

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation

So we all know that we can create directives in AngularJS. If not you should check it out. Anyways validation is a big deal to me to catch those annoying misspelling things that are constantly appearing in javascript. The same goes for the creation of directives with the camelcase and not in the html.

So I was wondering if there's a way that we can compile the angularJS code and validate the html on the fly. I'm working in Visual Studios 2012 and I sort of want an intellisense for the new directives.

For example

```
 var AppDirectives = angular.module('AppDirectives', [])
       .directive("myChart", [App.Directives.HighChartsDirective])
       .directive("myTable", [App.Directives.DataTablesDirective])
       .directive("datepicker", [App.Directives.DatePickerDirective]);
```

Is there a tool/way to have this code and have a validation telling me in my html that the 'my-chart' tag exist but not the 'mychart'.

Comment: In the case you described, Angularjs will give you an error if myChart does not exist. The error may not be as explicit as you want.

Comment: You can use Gulp.js or Grunt.js to watch and/or change these values.